# How to store a custom object in JSR223?

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I make my custom listener in Jmeter as JSR223 Listener.

Currently it appends records to text file then listener invoked, during test run (i think it's not good for test accuracy), but i'd like ot collect all data (by listeners) and save it in one peace after end of test (on teardown section)

Google finds a lot ways to store single variables like string, but it's not acceptable if I want to store tonns of complex sets of data. Is it possible to store somehow Java array (or something simular) of my custom objects via JSR223 as global variable (creates somewhere at setUp stage), available for every JSR223 lisneners/Samplers and etc?

If I made "datakeeper" singleton will it works as I expect (I don't know how GC works for JSR223, will it clean this or not, and will it available for other JSR223 instances) and is it good folution for my purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `props` shorthand which stands for normal [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which in its turn:

1. **global** and is accessible in other Thread Groups and everywhere in this [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) instance
2. can store whatever [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) you want, not only the String

So if you do something like:

```
 props.put('myObject', yourObject)
```

in the setUp Thread Group

you will be able to get the value as `props.get('myObject')` anywhere else

More information on this `props` and other JMeter API shorthands - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: It was not obvisious that I can store custom objects via put/get. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase from your question ***tonns of complex sets of data*** sounds alarm bells. Storing such large amount of data in memory will have adverse effect on your execution. You can expect threads to die unexpectedly majorly due `OutOfMemoryException`. Also, if JMeter crashes, you loose all the statistics captured until that point. You can tweak heap setting, but that is just a patch work and not a real solution to your problem statement.

You can continue with your current approach to save to local file.

Comment: I don't think that I have anought data to get OOM. "Tons of complex sets of data" is a small hyperbole. Anyway file operations is not so fast (as memory operations) and also i'm not sure that it's a good idea to write in one file from parallel threads (If I correctly understood Listeners invoked for every request as it finished, so possible the can try to write in one file in one time)

Comment: You still carry a risk of losing data due to jmeter hang / crash. `__StringToFile` in-built funnction of jmeter is thread safe